# What elements does a turing complete programming language need to consist of?

Tags: math, computer-science, turing-machines, turing-complete

I've been looking for this but came to nothing.

I saw this explanation once in some of the python's book out there but i don't remember which one.
So, what elements(variable, loop, branching, etc) a programming language should consist of being a turing complete?

Comment: Some interesting stuff: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine_equivalents), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer).

Comment: I wonder whether http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be the better place to ask this question. If you think it is, and ask the question there, please add the link in a comment then delete the question here. (The link is because high-rep users can see deleted questions and might benefit from the cross reference).

Comment: This question is too general to give a good answer. You can do things in very different ways, see for example the differences between functional and procedural languages. You will definitely need access to an unbounded amount of memory. But this can be achieved by allowing only one variable of a type that does not have size bounds; or by  recursion; or in other ways that maybe nobody has thought of yet...